# Variable Substitution in Python

Tags: python, string, web.py

So I'm working with Web.py and I have following code:

```
check = db.select('querycode', where='id=$id', vars=locals())[0]
```

Which works fine, it substitutes $id with the variable. But in this line it does not work:

```
web.sendmail('mail@mail.mail', "tomail@tomail.tomail", 'Subject', 'Hello $name')
```

What do I wrong and how could it work. Also did I get the concept right: A $-sign substitutes the variable?

Comment: The `vars=locals()` bit is a good indication that what is going on in the first example is done *inside* `db.select` rather than Python transforming the strings before passing them. In this case, it is done by *the database*, for security reasons - it helps to protect against [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) - and this feature actually *can't* be implemented securely at the Python level (the security depends on giving the db something more structured than one long string).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python does not in general do PHP-style variable interpolation.

What you are seeing in the first statement is a special feature of `db.select` which picks the variable values out of the local variables in the context of the caller.

If you want to substitute in the variable in your second line, you will have to do it manually with one of the ways Python provides. Here is one such way.

```
web.sendmail('mail@mail.mail', "tomail@tomail.tomail", 'Subject', 'Hello %s' % name)
```

Here is another way.

```
web.sendmail('mail@mail.mail', "tomail@tomail.tomail", 'Subject', 'Hello {0}'.format(name))
```

The first option is documented in [String Formatting operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).

See the documentation for [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) for more details on the second option.

Comment: Okay so it is like in C, do I have to use different %xxx for each type? Like Integer or char?

Comment: @yrk, For the first (older) method  yes, but for the second (newer) method no.

Comment: @yrk, I added some links to documentation for you to peruse on each of those methods.

Answer (score 12):

@merlin2011's answer explains it best.

But just to complement it, since you're trying to substitute *by variable name*, python also supports the following form of "substitution" (or string formatting):

```
'Hello %(name)s' % locals()
```

Or to limit the namespace:

```
'Hello %(name)s' % {'name': name}
```

---

EDIT
Since python 3.6, variable substitution is a done natively using [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).  E.g.,

```
print( f'Hello {name}' )
```